# How to setup TINYMCE to point to static_files?

Tags: django, django-tinymce

I am using Django 1.5.1, and as we know since Django 1.3 the world of Media and statis files have been separated for good reasons.

To my surprise django-tinymce's [documentation](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.5/installation.html#configuration) is referring to how TINYMCE_JS_URL is pointing by default to the media url.

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL (default: settings.MEDIA_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')
```

That doesn't make much sense. As in Django 1.3+ we have the static_url for self hosted js and css files.  But trying to change that is confusing and doesn't work.

This is how I usually setup my static files settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/kave/project-env/site/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/kave/project-env/site/static_files/',)
```

In the static_files directory I have extracted the TINYMCE zipfile:
e.g. the path is like this:

```
/home/kave/project-env/site/static_files/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js
```

Then I have set the settings like this:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL + 'tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT + 'tinymce/js/tinymce'
```

However when the app runs, I see a plain textfield instead of TINYMCE.

WHat could I have overlooked please?

Comment: Django-tinymce hasn't been updated in 4 years. I use TinyMCE in my Django projects, but have never felt the need use an app like this. You may consider just doing everything by hand, it isn't hard.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to have been authored only 12 days ago: https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce Hmm but I guess you are right, it is just a jquery really, which I could just do manually. Looking at download page: http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php it seems there is also a jquery build next to default build. Which one would you pick?

Comment: Oops, I might have been looking at a fork on github. It does look more recently updated. You can do a "view source" in your browser to see if the script tags are correct for your setup. That might give you some clues about what is happening.

Comment: If you already use jQuery on your site I'd probably grab that build.

Answer (score 4):

I have finally figured it out, hope it helps somebody else.

You need to point to the built-in tiny_mce that is automatically installed through pip.
No need to download anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

For admin screen, make sure you have this:

```
class TinyMCEAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', )

admin.site.register(MyModel, TinyMCEAdmin)
```

And don't forget the config in settings.py

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    # General options
    'mode' : "textareas",
    'theme' : "advanced",
    'plugins' : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

    # Theme options
    'theme_advanced_buttons1' : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,fontselect,fontsizeselect,", #fullscreen,code",
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    #'theme_advanced_buttons3' : "tablecontrols,|,hr,sub,sup,|,charmap",

    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : "top",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' : "left",
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' : "bottom",
    'theme_advanced_resizing' : 'true',

    #Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    #content_css : "/css/style.css",

    'template_external_list_url' : "lists/template_list.js",
    'external_link_list_url' : "lists/link_list.js",
    'external_image_list_url' : "lists/image_list.js",
    'media_external_list_url' : "lists/media_list.js",

    # Style formats
    'style_formats' : [
        {'title' : 'Bold text', 'inline' : 'strong'},
        {'title' : 'Red text', 'inline' : 'span', 'styles' : {'color' : '#ff0000'}},
        {'title' : 'Help', 'inline' : 'strong', 'classes' : 'help'},
        {'title' : 'Table styles'},
        {'title' : 'Table row 1', 'selector' : 'tr', 'classes' : 'tablerow'}
    ],

    'width': '700',
    'height': '400'
}
```

Other than that make sure to use the HTMLField inside your model for any model textfield.
In forms.py, if you are not using modelform, you need to define the new widget as well.

Answer (score 0):

To make work with django-tinymce

we have to configure the following

> settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # .......
  'tinymce',
  # .......
]

TINYMCE_JS_URL = '%sjavascript/tiny_mce/' % (STATIC_URL)
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  # .....
  url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
  # .....
]
```